# Getting an invalid route action error in Laravel 10

Tags: laravel, authentication, routes, laravel-10

I'm getting an UnexpectedValueException error message: "Invalid route action: [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController]."

`Did you forget to add the` __invoke `method or is the controller's method missing in your routes file?`

I don't use invokable controllers, and the method is not missing in my routes file. I can't use artisan or load any pages.

routes/web/auth.php:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('login', [LoginController::class, 'create'])
    ->name('auth.login.create');

Route::post('login', [LoginController::class, 'store'])
    ->name('auth.login.store');

Route::post('logout', [LoginController::class, 'delete'])
    ->name('auth.logout');
```

App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\LoginRequest;
use App\Traits\LoginTrait;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

final class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use LoginTrait;

    private const HOME_ROUTE = 'home.index';

    public function create(): View
    {
        return view('auth.login', [
            'title' => 'Log In'
        ]);
    }

    public function store(LoginRequest $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        $credentials = [
            'samaccountname' => $request->username,
            'password' => $request->password
        ];

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();

            $message = $this->getSuccessMessage();

            $request->session()->flash('success', $message);

            return redirect()->intended();
        }

        $request->session()->flash('error', 'The provided credentials do not match our records.');

        return back()->onlyInput('username');
    }

    public function delete(Request $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        Auth::logout();

        $request->session()->invalidate();
        $request->session()->regenerateToken();
        $request->session()->flash('success', 'You have been logged out.');

        return redirect()->route(self::HOME_ROUTE);
    }
}
```

I copied the imports from the Laravel docs into the LoginController.

Comment: Step one is always clear the caches including route cache. `artisan optimize:clear`

Comment: I get the error if I run php artisan by itself or with anything, including optimize, route:clear, route:list, etc.

Comment: I think it’s stored in `storage/framework/cache/` and you can delete everything in there.  `composer dump-autoload` is another one to try, though it definitely sounds more like cache than an autoloader problem.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I'm using Filament and was trying to use the same login controller. This code in config/filament.php was causing the error:

```
   'pages' => [
        'login' => \App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController::class
    ]
```